# python unittest ModuleNotFoundError: No module named <...>

Tags: python, import, python-unittest

I tried to crate simple Python project with `flask` and `unittest`. Structure is quite simple:

```
classes
  |-sysinfo
      |static
      |templates
         |- index.html
         |- layout.html
      |__init__.py
      |sysinfo.py
      |printinfo.py
  tests
  |test_sysinfo.py
README.md
requirments.txt
```

Very simple class in `printinfo.py`:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
import psutil
import json
class SysInfo:
.......
    def displayInfo(self):
        .......
        return json.dumps(self.__data)
```

And simple flask server run with `sysinfo.py`:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session, abort
from printinfo import SysInfo
import json
obj1 = SysInfo("gb")
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def index():
    var = json.loads(obj1.displayInfo())
    return render_template('index.html',**locals())
@app.route('/healthcheck')
def healthcheck():
    return "Ok"
@app.route("/api/all")
def all():
    return obj1.displayInfo()
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=80)
del obj1
```

I run it with python `sysinfo.py` staying in `classes/sysinfo` folder and everything works ok.

So I decided to run unittest for my application. Put in `classes/tests` ( also tried `classes/sysinfo/tests`) file `test_sysinfo.py` with code:

```
import unittest
import printinfo
from sysinfo import sysinfo
import json
import sys
class TestFlaskApi(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.app = sysinfo.app.test_client()
    def simple_test(self):
        response = self.app.get('/health')
        self.assertEqual(
            json.loads(response.get_data().decode(sys.getdefaultencoding())),
            {'healthcheck': 'ok'}
        )
if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

And when I started it I can see error:

```
Error Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "\Python\Python37-32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 59, in testPartExecutor
     yield   File "\Python\Python37-32\lib\unittest\case.py", line 615, in run
     testMethod()   File "\Python\Python37-32\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 34, in testFailure
     raise self._exception ImportError: Failed to import test module: test_sysinfo Traceback (most recent call last):   File
 "\Python\Python37-32\lib\unittest\loader.py", line 154, in
 loadTestsFromName
     module = __import__(module_name)   File "\classes\sysinfo\tests\test_sysinfo.py", line 2, in <module>
     import printinfo ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'printinfo'
```

I read several articles, some topics here on StackOverflow for my understanding it's related to project structure. I tried to create `setup.py` and `setup.cfg`. I managed to start it with this setup, but test still didn't work.

Could you please help me with minimum setup applicable for my case? All the material I found had written for specific case or too general. I cannot apply it for my case.

Comment: it's a `sys.path` issue. If you run the test via `python classes/tests/test_sysinfo.py`, the `classes/sysinfo` directory will not be present in `sys.path`, so Python is unable to import the `printinfo` module. Without doing further project structure modifications, you can add the directory to `sys.path` explicitly as a workaround: `PYTHONPATH=classes/sysinfo/ python classes/tests/test_sysinfo.py`.

Comment: However, it looks like your imports are a bit messy. `sysinfo` is a package, so you should import `printinfo` via `from sysinfo import printinfo` (as you already do that with the other module: `from sysinfo import sysinfo`). When fixed, add `classes` to `sys.path` (as it's the parent dir of the `sysinfo` package) and the imports issue should be resolved: `PYTHONPATH=classes python classes/tests/test_sysinfo.py`

Comment: I tried and now it raised another error related to code, module error is missing. Thank you @hoefling I already started refactore code to run my code as module from setup.py. Read manuals and try to adapt it to my reality.

Comment: I'm ready to give up ( According to documentation decided to init application in `__init__.py`. Here is code: `def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev'
    )

    from . import printinfo
    # Create printenv class instance
    obj1 = printinfo.SysInfo("gb")` the same error... `flask.cli.NoAppException: While importing "sysinfo", an ImportError was raised:`

Comment: Can you edit the question, adding the new bits of code and the new error trace?

Answer (score 0):

Follow flask tutorial I edit `__init__.py` file to start app from here:

```
from flask import Flask, flash, redirect, render_template, request, session, abort
from . import printinfo
import json
import os

obj1 = printinfo.SysInfo("gb")

def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)
    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev'
    )

    obj1 = printinfo.SysInfo("gb")

    @app.route('/')
    def index():
        var = json.loads(obj1.displayInfo())
        return render_template('index.html', **locals())

    @app.route('/healthcheck')
    def healthcheck():
        return "Ok"

    @app.route("/api/all")
    def all():
        return obj1.displayInfo()

    #del obj1
    return app
```

Also environment variables should be set for Flask:
For Linux and Mac:

```
export FLASK_APP=sysinfo
export FLASK_ENV=development
```

For Windows cmd, use set instead of export:

```
set FLASK_APP=sysinfo
set FLASK_ENV=development
```

And run application:

```
flask run
```

It run application on localhost on port 5000 since development env set. Anyway I needed to add `from . import printinfo` into `__init__.py`.

Didn't try test, but think it should work. If interesting will update soon.

Answer (score 0):

Just followed Flask tutorial. Created `conftest.py` and `test_factory.py`. Run Ok with `pytest`:

```
import pytest
from sysinfo import create_app
from sysinfo import printinfo

@pytest.fixture
def app():
    app = create_app({
        'TESTING': True
    })

    with app.app_context():
        printinfo.SysInfo("gb")

    yield app
```

Probably the same setup could be used with `unittest`. Didn't try.